# Jenkins secret text credential as variable in pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a credential `test_cred` of type secret text to store a password, which should be passed to an ansible playbook.
I am passing this parameter as an extra variable `root_pass` to ansible, but the value `root_pass` is evaluated to string `test_cred` instead of the secret text contained in it. Can somebody please help to get the value of the credential `test_cred` so that I can pass it to ansible.

```
stages {
    stage('Execution') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'test_cred', variable: 'test')]) {
            }
            ansiblePlaybook(
                installation: 'ansible',
                inventory: "inventory/hosts",
                playbook: "${PLAYBOOK}",
                extraVars: [
                    server: "${params.Server}",
                    client: "${params.Client}",
                    root_pass: "${test}"
                ]
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `ansiblePlaybook' block be entirely inside the `withCredentials` step ?

Comment: Yes,  Zeitounator I have corrected it, now working as expected!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: I am newer to the pipeline scripts. Just wondering If I have one more credential say ```credentialsId: 'test_cred2'```, how can I assign it to another variable?

Comment: `withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'credid1', variable: 'test1'), string(credentialsId: 'credid2', variable: 'test2')])`

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you @Zeitounator!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you Zeitounator. The working code is:

```
stages {
    stage('Execution') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'test_cred', variable: 'test')]) {
            
            ansiblePlaybook(
                installation: 'ansible',
                inventory: "inventory/hosts",
                playbook: "${PLAYBOOK}",
                extraVars: [
                    server: "${params.Server}",
                    client: "${params.Client}",
                    root_pass: "${test}"
                ]
            )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should be able to further simplify `"${PLAYBOOK}"` to `PLAYBOOK`, `"${params.Server}"` to `params.Server`, `"${params.Client}"` to `"params.Client`, and `"${test}"` to `test`.